# AspNetUsers to IdentityUser with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-membership

### Background

I have a project written with C# and ASP.NET core (v2.2). This project is connected to a database that holds a table called "AspNetUsers". The building strategy is "Database First".

I'm building the models from the data with this command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "...DB-CS..." PROVIDER -Context UsersDB -f -OutputDir Processes\Models
```

Then it's created for me this mapped class:

```
public partial class AspNetUsers
{
    public AspNetUsers()
    {

    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationTime { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

On my website, I'm using the `UserManager` class. This class is expecting to get an Object that inherits from the `IdentityUser` interface.

### The Question:

Is this possible to make my `AspNetUsers` class implementing `IdentityUser`?

Thanks!

### Update #1

Thanks for @Darjan Bogdan answer, I created this new file:

```
public partial class AspNetUsers : IdentityUser
{
}
```

and changed my `UserManager` to looks like this:

```
private UserManager<AspNetUsers> UserManager { get; set; }
```

On first looks, it looks like work. When going deeper to check this - I got many strange errors like :

```
User security stamp cannot be null.
```

Although AspNetUsers instance **has** `SecuriyStamp` field (not null).
I checked the `AspNetUsers` file (auto-generated) and it seems like some properties are **hiding** another.

[image]

Question: I working in **Database first** model. So, the AspNetUsers file is auto-generated. How to avoid hiding other properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it, there is a reason why code generators create `partial` [classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods).

So, in order for `AspNetUsers` to inherit `IdentityUser` you just need to define following in another (not generated) file, in e.g. *AspnetUsers.Partial.cs* file:

```
public partial class AspnetUsers : IdentityUser
{

}
```

Please note, that you **should not** change the file which is generated, but rather create your own folder in which you will add additional files with partial classes.

Worth to mention, you need to use **the same namespace** when extending partial class.

Comment: Seems like this advice is getting us closer to the solution. See `Update #1` on my question

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever it seems that your database schema doesn't fully follow default database schema created when using `IdentityUser` class only. So in order to make it work, you should override properties which are different (e.g. Null/NotNull, different Length, etc...) in your partial class. Besides that, you might need to use your own `IdentityDbContext<AspnetUsers>` in which you'll override  default configuration via `OnModelCreating` method, to adapt it to your "slightly" different schema. Afterwards, you'll need to make `UserManager` to use `UserStore` which uses your custom `DbContext`

Answer (score 0):

You dont realy need to implement IdentityUser unless you have custom data on it

```
using System;

namespace WebApp1.Areas.Identity.Data
{
    public class WebApp1User : IdentityUser
    {
        [PersonalData]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Take a look here [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah its possible and that's the normal way you should do it. In you case, from the auto generated AspNetUser class, remove properties that are inhering from the IdentityUser and keep only that are not inhering.

```
public class AspNetUser : IdentityUser<string> 
{
    public DateTime RegistrationTime { get; set; }
    public string OtherPros {get;set;},
}
```

Then you can use AspNetUser class with UserManager.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public partial class AspNetUsers : IdentityUser
{
    public AspNetUsers()
    {

    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegistrationTime { get; set; }    
}
```